# OnBackButtonPressed-Event not reached

Tags: xaml, maui, back-button

In my .NET MAUI App, I navigate to one of my ContentPages via:

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ManagePeopleItem), true);`

The page is registered in AppShell.xaml.cs via:

`Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ManagePeopleItem), typeof(ManagePeopleItem));`

So, when I display this Page, I can see the Back Button "<-" in my Navigation Bar. But when I click this Button and override "OnBackButtonPressed()" this Code is never reached. I also tried to override it in AppShell.xaml.cs, but it is also not fired there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AppShell's override back button does method doesn't work? That's interesting can i see your code once?

Comment: Well, that is just a simple Override in AppShell.xaml.cs:

`public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ManagePeopleItem), typeof(ManagePeopleItem));
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
}`

Comment: I also tried the following:

`public partial class ManagePeopleItem : ContentPage
{
    public ManagePeopleItem(ManagePeopleItemViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel;

        var shell = (App.Current.MainPage as Shell);
        shell.Navigating += Shell_Navigating;
    }

    private void Shell_Navigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source == ShellNavigationSource.Pop)
        {
           ....
        }
    }
}`

EventHandler is reached, but how can I detect it was by "<-" Button

Comment: @OXO Please don't put code in comments, update the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code you provided. And it shows the same situation happened to you.

I searched relevant cases about it. Finally I found this: [On Screen Back Button Does Not Fire OnBackButtonPressed in Android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9095) on GitHub. When you run it on Windows instead of Android, OnBackButtonPressed-Event can be reached. But for Android, it can't. You can follow up this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, overriding the OnBackButtonPressed in AppShell.xaml.cs did not work. When I set my Breakpoint to the Beginning of this Method, it did not reach it

Comment: @OXO Yes, your situation is the same as mine. This is an issue. And [it](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9095) is Open, not Closed. I mean you can follow up this issue and see if there's any new developments about it.

Comment: Okay, I marked it as answered, so other can follow this topic, even if there is no solution right now. In my case, I was lucky and could to my logic also in the OnNavigatingFrom